# Backgroundworker in VB not working?

Tags: vb.net

Im writing an app that takes and copy's folders (selected by the user in a listbox) to a specified location, it has a progress bar that should run the whole time but it seems that the backgroundworker isnt catching the process.. it just freezes the UI until the copy is complete.. when I put in a message between copy's the message works so I know it is capable of  working.. im missing something..

```
Private Sub Button4_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Btn_SaveApps.Click

    bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    bw.WorkerReportsProgress = True

    AddHandler bw.DoWork, AddressOf bw_DoWork
    AddHandler bw.ProgressChanged, AddressOf bw_ProgressChanged
    AddHandler bw.RunWorkerCompleted, AddressOf bw_RunWorkerCompleted
    If Not bw.IsBusy = True Then
        bw.RunWorkerAsync(Module1.SaveApp)
    End If

End Sub       

Module Module1
Function SaveApp() As Process

    Dim WinStrApps As String = ("C:\TransferFrom")
    Form1.tbProgress.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee

    For Each Item In Form1.Selected_Apps.SelectedItems
        On Error Resume Next

        Form1.tbProgress.Visible = True

        Dim FileLoc = ("C:\TransferTo\")
        If System.IO.Directory.Exists(WinStrApps + Item) = True Then

            Directory.CreateDirectory(FileLoc + Item)
            My.Computer.FileSystem.CopyDirectory(WinStrApps + Item, FileLoc + Item)

        Else
            MsgBox(Item + " does not exist, or is a system App. Please choose another application")

        End If
    Next

    MsgBox("Completed saving the applications")

End Function
```

Comment: Please look at the example at the bottom of this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks! Reading that right now

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have called the thread wrong, the thread has to begin in the sub bw_DoWork

```
Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)
    Module1.SaveApp
end sub
```

and any updates passed back to the UI thread need to be passed to

```
Private Sub bw_ProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs)
    Form1.tbProgress.value = e.ProgressPercentage
End Sub
```

however you wont be able to access the update routine from your sub as the routine is private of Form1... you may have to create a delegate in your module.

Comment: How would I send the command back from bw_DoWork to BtnSaveApps.Click? I get an error 

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs' to type 'System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs'.

im reading the article from the msdn article right now, i must be missing something lol

Comment: You can't. What you are trying to do is pass things from a worker thread to your UI thread you simply cant do this. You may be better off using System.Threading instead of a background worker. Why do you need to pass arguments back to the click event? The only events within your backgroundworker that can "communicate" with the UI thread in this case is from the subs bw_ProgressChanged and bw_RunWorkerCompleted

Comment: Remember, calling your function from the background worker means that instance of the function is now on the background thread and cannot directly communicate with the UI.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense.. I am trying to get the file transfer to show progress, it could be a few files, or over a gig in files being copied so when the UI freezes it appears that it the program is broken.. I have tried using a few versions of the file copy progress bar but each one has an issue..

The main process should enumerate each copy as the folder lets say C:\Programs\App1 than copy App1 to C:\Programs_To\App1 and the next App2,App3 etc. When App1 is finished I want the progress bar that is on my 2nd form to get the report and update % based on x of folders copied of x total folders.

Comment: I understand, it's not a thread issue it's an IO issue. What you may need to do is perform byte level copies, eg a 1204byte buffer stream